# How to seek in CTR mode and decrypt part of the stream?

Tags: c++, encryption, decode, crypto++

I have a question in partial decoding in cryptopp. 
USE AES 256 CTR;

Encode source:

```cxx
CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
e.SetKeyWithIV(key, 32, iv);
string encrypt;
string a = "Example text to encoding";
encrypt.clear();
StringSource s(a, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
        new StringSink(encrypt)
    )
);
```

Decode source:

```cxx
CTR_Mode<AES>::Decryption d;
d.SetKeyWithIV(key, 32, iv);
string x;

StringSource s1(encrypt, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
        new StringSink(x)
    )
);
```

It works fine. But I don't know how decrypt only part. For example, example `encrypt.begin()+10`

Part Decode:

```cxx
CTR_Mode<AES>::Decryption d;
d.SetKeyWithIV(key, 32, iv);
d.DiscardBytes(5);  //bit to skip
string todecrypt = encrypt.substr(5,10); // part of encrypted message
string x;

StringSource s1(todecrypt, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
        new StringSink(x)
    )
);
```

Comment: +10 here wouldn't make sense. You must decrypt an entire 16-byte block no matter what your block mode is. Are you actually trying to solve this for much larger offsets (this is possible with CTR, but somewhat complex, and I can't remember if Crypto++ has direct support, so there may be significant code required to achieve this)? For small offsets, there's no benefit; just throw away the first N bytes.

Comment: @jww this still has to decrypt 16 bytes. AES always encrypts/decrypts 16 bytes. So if you're decrypting byte 10, you have to also have decrypted bytes 0-9. The fact that the key changes rather than the data doesn't change that. You note this yourself: "modulo 16 to seek." So decrypting byte 10 is identical to just decrypting normally and throwing away bytes 0-9 of the output (which is simple). Throwing away the right amount of cipher text is possible as you say (totally agree) and CTR allows it. It's just complicated in *code* unless library is designed for it & I think Crypto++ isn't.

Comment: Ok. I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

> How to seek in CTR mode and decrypt part of the stream?

Using a [Crypto++ Pipeline](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) is a tad bit awkward because [`Discard` or `Skip` on a `Source` does not work as expected](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/248). You have to `Pump` data into *"nothing"* under the current implementation. Also see [Skip'ing on a Source does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39166041/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Below is an example of using AES/CTR and seeking in the stream. It needs to perform a "two part" seek. First, it discards bytes on the `Source` called `cipher`. Second, it seeks in the keystream on the encryption object called `enc` to synchronize the counter. Once the seek is performed, the remainder of the cipher text is decrypted by calling `PumpAll()`, which pumps the remainder of the data through the pipeline.

```cxx
#include "modes.h"
#include "aes.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string plain = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country";

    byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH] = {0};
    byte nonce[AES::BLOCKSIZE] = {0};

    CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), nonce, sizeof(nonce));

    string cipher;
    StringSource ss1(plain, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(enc, new StringSink(cipher)));

    for(size_t i=0; i<cipher.size(); i++)
    {   
        CTR_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
        dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), nonce, sizeof(nonce));

        StringSource ss2(cipher, false);
        ss2.Pump(i);
        dec.Seek(i);

        string recover;
        StreamTransformationFilter stf(dec, new StringSink(recover));

        // Attach the decryption filter after seeking
        ss2.Attach(new Redirector(stf));
        ss2.PumpAll();

        cout << i << ": " << recover << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
$ ./test.exe 
0: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
1: ow is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
2: w is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
3:  is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
4: is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
5: s the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
6:  the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
7: the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
8: he time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
9: e time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
10:  time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
11: time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
12: ime for all good men to come to the aide of their country
13: me for all good men to come to the aide of their country
14: e for all good men to come to the aide of their country
15:  for all good men to come to the aide of their country
16: for all good men to come to the aide of their country
17: or all good men to come to the aide of their country
18: r all good men to come to the aide of their country
19:  all good men to come to the aide of their country
20: all good men to come to the aide of their country
21: ll good men to come to the aide of their country
22: l good men to come to the aide of their country
23:  good men to come to the aide of their country
24: good men to come to the aide of their country
25: ood men to come to the aide of their country
26: od men to come to the aide of their country
27: d men to come to the aide of their country
28:  men to come to the aide of their country
29: men to come to the aide of their country
30: en to come to the aide of their country
31: n to come to the aide of their country
32:  to come to the aide of their country
33: to come to the aide of their country
34: o come to the aide of their country
35:  come to the aide of their country
36: come to the aide of their country
37: ome to the aide of their country
38: me to the aide of their country
39: e to the aide of their country
40:  to the aide of their country
41: to the aide of their country
42: o the aide of their country
43:  the aide of their country
44: the aide of their country
45: he aide of their country
46: e aide of their country
47:  aide of their country
48: aide of their country
49: ide of their country
50: de of their country
51: e of their country
52:  of their country
53: of their country
54: f their country
55:  their country
56: their country
57: heir country
58: eir country
59: ir country
60: r country
61:  country
62: country
63: ountry
64: untry
65: ntry
66: try
67: ry
68: y
```

---

Now that you've seen the general pattern, here are the modifications for your dataset using the range `[5,10]`.

You do *not* have to call `stf.MessageEnd()` because recovered text is ready as soon as the XOR is preformed. Others modes may need the call to `MessageEnd()`. Also see [Init-Update-Final](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Init-Update-Final) on the Crypto++ wiki.

```cxx
StringSource ss2(cipher, false);
ss2.Pump(5);
dec.Seek(5);

string recover;
StreamTransformationFilter stf(dec, new StringSink(recover));

// Attach the decryption filter after seeking
ss2.Attach(new Redirector(stf));
ss2.Pump(10 - 5 + 1);

cout << "'" << recover << "'" << endl;
```

It produces:

```
$ ./test.exe 
's the '
```

And here's a little more:

```cxx
StringSource ss2(cipher, false);
ss2.Pump(5);
dec.Seek(5);

string recover;
StreamTransformationFilter stf(dec, new StringSink(recover));

// Attach the decryption filter after seeking
ss2.Attach(new Redirector(stf));
ss2.Pump(10 - 5 + 1);

cout << "'" << recover << "'" << endl;

ss2.Pump(1);

cout << "'" << recover << "'" << endl;

ss2.Pump(1);

cout << "'" << recover << "'" << endl;
```

It produces:

```
$ ./test.exe 
's the '
's the t'
's the ti'
```

---

Earlier I said *"Using a [Crypto++ Pipeline](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) is a tad bit awkward"*. Here's all we want to do, but we can't at the moment:

```cxx
StringSource ss(cipher, false, new StreamTransformationFilter(dec, new StringSink(x)));
ss.Skip(5); // Discard bytes and synchronize stream
ss.Pump(5); // Process bytes [5,10]

cout << x << endl;
```

---

Regarding Rob's comment *"You must decrypt an entire 16-byte block..."* - If you were working with another mode, like CBC mode, then you would have to process preceding plain text or cipher text; and you would have to operate on blocks. CBC mode and its chaining properties demand it.

However, CTR is designed a little differently. Its designed to be seekable, and it allows you to jump around in the stream. In this respect, its a lot like OFB mode. (CTR mode and OFB mode differ in the way they generate the keystream. But both XOR the keystream with the plain text or cipher text).